# Is it possible to put an ngFor inside an ngIf?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I'am trying since two days now to parse a Json file with nested object inside who's himself inside an ngIf...the code will be more explicite I think:

So imagine this is a child component opening conditionally from a parent event coming from a button:

My http service is working because I already use it in some other components and the observable is "user3"

The parent html:

```
    <div class="parent">
        <img src="fold_down_black.png" type="button"(click)="toggleChild()"/>
    <div><my-child [showMePartially]="showVar" ></my-child></div>
    </div>
```

I bind it using input as following in the child.ts:

```
      @Input() showMePartially: boolean;
```

Here's the child.html:

```
 <div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="child" >
   <span id="tfonc" *ngFor="let user3 of userService3.users3 | async">Fonctionnal duration : {{user3.data.operating_rate}}%
   </span>
</div>
```

Here's my service:

```
 export interface User3 {
 data: any;
}
   const usersURL = 'http://my.supa.json;php';

@Injectable()
export class UserService3 {

  users3: Observable<User3[]>;

    constructor (public http: Http) {


          getData() {

     const tick3$ = Observable.timer(100, 60000);

     return tick3$.flatMap(() => this.http.get(usersURL)).map(res => 
res.json());   // .publishBehavior(<User3[]>[]).refCount();
```

When i did so nothing in the view and nothing in the console also...thanks in avance for the help..I suppose the conflict is comming from an ngFor inside an ngIf...

Comment: You're trying to loop observable. Subscribe to it in your child.ts and assign emitted data to some new prop with initial value of [] and loop through it instead. Alternatively, from 4.x you can use `async` pipe: http://angularjs.blogspot.com.by/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Comment: @wostex yes I want to use the async pipe as well I update my post with...I tough I was subscribing to it because I inject my userService who's already subscribed in my constructor like :  constructor(public userService3: UserService3) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

} ...is that correct?

Comment: @wostex should I subscribe again like for exemple: public ngOnInit () {
    this.dataSubscription = this.userService3 (if dataSubscription: Subscription;)

Comment: Is `users3` a subscription or an observable? If it's observable you need to subscribe to it in your component. Service injection has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @wostex users3 is an Observable you right, so I don't need to inject my service in the consctructor? I didn't know about it...I updated my post with my service too

Comment: @wostex I did so in my child.ts but I still see nothing appear in my view: public ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSubscription = this.userService3.getData().subscribe(() => {

    });
  }
      public ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.dataSubscription) {
this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
    }

}

Comment: I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is you're trying to loop through `users3` observable. You need to subscribe to it instead in your child.ts. Inside your Child class:

```
myUsers = [];
sub: Subscription;

// inject a service. don't forget to import userService3 also
constructor(private userService: userService3) {}  

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.userService.users3.subscribe(users => this.myUsers = users) // subscribe!
}
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

In your template:

```
*ngFor="let user3 of users3
```

Comment: @EmileCantero I've edited it a bit so that you could see a difference between props.

Comment: thanks for help, sounds like your code is returning any error in the console but I still got nothing in my view..strange...also from your point of view shouldn't use ngOndestroy then as so?  ngOnDestroy() {
     if (this.users3) {
this.users3.unsubscribe();
}
   }

Comment: @EmileCantero you're right onDestroy is needed here but it's not the point of the question. It should work now; the only thing I can think of is your `users3` observable doesn't emit anything or not implemented properly.

Comment: yes I think it should work too..maybe it's about css or html..I'll let you know because I've got many nested child component (maybe z-index property...)